# 'attempt to index field 'Colors' (a nil value)' When accessing an array in LUA

Tags: arrays, lua, null, roblox

So I decided to try and pickup LUA for roblox JUST as the forums.roblox.com dies, if there is a better place to ask please let me know.

Anyway I am trying to make a block randomly change between several predefined colors. The way I am attempting to do this is to make an array with the colors and then use math.random to pick a location in the array to set as the color, all within a while 1==1 loop that repeats every 1 second.

Here is my code

```
Colors = {'Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Camo', 'Blue', 'Pink', 'Purple'}

while(1 == 1)
do
    script.Parent.BrickColor = BrickColor.Colors[math.random(1,7)]
    wait(1)
end
```

Whenever I run it I get the error "Workspace.Part.Script:5: attempt to index field 'Colors' (a nil value)"

But if I try

```
Colors = {'Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Camo', 'Blue', 'Pink', 'Purple'}

while(1 == 1)
do
    --script.Parent.BrickColor = BrickColor.Colors[math.random(1,7)]
    Colors[math.random(1,7)]
    wait(1)
end
```

it will print out one of the colors once a second.

Like I said I am just starting so it could be something dumb.

Comment: The second piece of code does not compile.

Comment: Ok, do you know something I could do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> script.Parent.BrickColor = BrickColor.Colors[math.random(1,7)]

You are referencing field `Colors` in `BrickColor`, whereas you should just reference the variable `Colors` you created earlier:

```
script.Parent.BrickColor = Colors[math.random(1,7)]
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. The problem I now have is that it outputs 'bad argument #3 to 'BrickColor' (BrickColor expected, got string)' or if I remove the single quotes so the array reads 
Colors = {Red, Orange, Yellow, Camo, Blue, Pink, Purple}
I get 'bad argument #3 to 'BrickColor' (BrickColor expected, got nil)'

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after trying Pauls suggestion to change the brick color line to

```
script.Parent.BrickColor = Colors[math.random(1,7)]
```

I got the error

```
bad argument #3 to 'BrickColor' (BrickColor expected, got string)
```

after some more searching I found out that I needed to use BrickColor.new(color) to change the color. This is how the code looked in the end

```
Colors = {'Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Camo', 'Blue', 'Pink', 'Purple'}

while(1 == 1)
do
    script.Parent.BrickColor = BrickColor.new(Colors[math.random(1,7)])
    wait(1)
end
```